# Python AES ECB Mode with Crypto

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes

I tried to implement some encryption for some old hardware which uses the AES ECB.

But if I only decrypt the message it didn't work.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import binascii

key = b'ABCDEFGHIJIKLMOP'
#cipher = AES.new(key.encode("utf8"), AES.MODE_ECB)
#msg = cipher.encrypt(b'a4dd23fff740b203efe19d5cbbc24bba')
msg = (b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA')
#print(type(msg))
#print(msg.hex())
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)


msg_en = cipher.encrypt(msg)
print("       ")
print(binascii.hexlify(msg_en))
#print(type(msg_en))

print("--------")
decipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)

msg_dec = decipher.decrypt(msg_en)
print(msg_dec)
print(binascii.hexlify(msg_dec))
#print(type(msg_dec))
```

```
Output : b'75ce1408b210410124729691da93c439'
         --------
         b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
         b'41414141414141414141414141414141'
```

If I replace the decrypt with the origin encrypted message I get this:

```
print("--------")
decipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)

msg_dec = decipher.decrypt(b"75ce1408b210410124729691da93c439")
print(msg_dec)
print(binascii.hexlify(msg_dec))
#print(type(msg_dec))
```

```
Output:
      b'75ce1408b210410124729691da93c439'
      --------
      b'\xed}\xcc\xbbI\xae\x11su\xea\xbc9s|\xb2\xc8\x94\x00\xb9\x93\xe4\xdf\xaf\xb8\xffU\xfc\xccS\r'
      b'ed7dccbb49ae117375eabc39737cb2c89400b993e4dfafb8ff552ffc49cc530d'
```

I don't get it.

Comment: Your Output : b'75ce1408b210410124729691da93c439' is in hex encoding (for printing reasons) so if you take that data you first have to convert it back to binary form.

Answer (score 3):

Okay , thanks to Michael Fehr.

Solution:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import binascii


key = b'ABCDEFGHIJIKLMOP'
#cipher = AES.new(key.encode("utf8"), AES.MODE_ECB)
#msg = cipher.encrypt(b'a4dd23fff740b203efe19d5cbbc24bba')
msg = (b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA')
#print(type(msg))
#print(msg.hex())
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)


msg_en = cipher.encrypt(msg)
print("       ")
print(binascii.hexlify(msg_en))
#print(type(msg_en))

print("--------")
decipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)

msg_dec = decipher.decrypt(binascii.unhexlify(b"75ce1408b210410124729691da93c439")) # Decipher akzeptiert und Binary kein Hex
print(msg_dec)
print(binascii.hexlify(msg_dec))
#print(type(msg_dec))
```

```
Output : 
       
b'75ce1408b210410124729691da93c439'
--------
b'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
b'41414141414141414141414141414141'
```

But one last question. Why put it first in Binary and then decrypt it?

Comment: In your first example the "hex conversion" was just for print out reasons, you took the encrypting output as direct input to your decryption function. The second way is a "stand alone decryption" so you have to "reencode" the (hex encoded) input to binary as input for decryption.